# expected scalar type Long but found Float in PyTorch, using nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I wanted to make a label torch tensor. I chose two different ways which the first one makes an error in the part of calculating loss with `nn.CrossEntropyLoss()`. I want to know why this happens, although the tensor results are the same.

The **first** method:

```
labels = torch.hstack((torch.zeros(100),torch.ones(100),1+torch.ones(100)))
```

The **second** method:

```
labels_np = np.vstack((np.zeros((100,1)),np.ones((100,1)),1+np.ones((100,1))))
labels = torch.squeeze(torch.tensor(labels_np).long())
```

**Error**:

```
expected scalar type Long but found Float in Pytoch
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix your **first method**, you should change the type by calling `labels = labels.long()` to transform the data type:

```py
labels = torch.hstack((torch.zeros(100),torch.ones(100),1+torch.ones(100)))
labels = labels.long()
```